# Rails devise user architecture for social network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, social-networking

Im creating a social network app with rails and devise as the user authentication gem. I have more than one type of user and dont know how to proceed.

My userType1 and userType2 have very little in common so I dont know if STI is the way to go.

Should I have both user types inherit from Devise User or should I create each one with devise.

Last, should I create all the social fields in the user type or create a profile model for this type of info

Any help is greatly appreciated

The first type of user is a customer that has basic fields like first name, last name, profile photo, and home address.

The second type of user is an agent that has many other fields, like first name, last name, profile photo, business informations(address, phone ..etc), specialty, category, title, website, social accts, and other fields.

The difference in functionality between the two is great, the agent user will act as a friend, tag, create events, listings etc... and the customer will only create lsitings, contact agents, and search for listings.

Comment: Your question is too broad. We don't know what level of experience you have, so any answers we give are shooting in the dark, hoping it'll make sense to you. In order to explain correctly we'd have to write a tutorial starting from the beginning and working up. Please provide more information so we don't have to only give opinions based on guesses.

Comment: @theTinMan I have edited my question to have more infomation about the user models

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously rethink the idea of having two models for your user types. Instead, consider having a slim User model and use associations (like User.profile, User.details) to hold the extra attributes. This will save you a lot of headaches by preventing you from addressing different "user" models in your devise code.

Comment: But then I would need to create two types of profiles to hold the different types of attributes for each user @errata

Comment: It's better than creating different "user" classes that both inherit from Devise IMO.

Comment: I like this alternative, however how would I go about doing the associations between the user and the profiles. I would have the user model have one of each profile? @errata

Comment: You could have a related model that can accommodate both and possibly has a type field.. that seems clumsy tho. I find NOSQL or postgres array types to be a better fit for dynamic or changing data structures.

Comment: You could also define the profile as a polymorphic association to use various profile classes associated with users

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, without details about the differences between the user models, a specific answer is hard to provide, but here is some stuff to consider:

Devise is used for handling user registration, sign in, and content management.

If your two user types will be creating their accounts the same way, signing in the same way, or viewing mostly the same content, it may not be worthwhile having two models, since minor differences can be stored in the models themselves.

If your two users differ greatly in function, then having them separate may make your code more readable.  If they differ greatly in concept, it may also pay to have the separate, for the sake of making your code match your domain model.

Make sure to consider how the two different types of users will be registering/logging in.  If they are intended to use the same pages/forms, then handling two different types will become very complex immediately, probably prohibitively so.

Comment: I added more information about the models. Im aiming to have them user the same forms for registration, sign in and other forms